# Синхронизация анимаций в Unity (архитектура решения)

Tags: c#, архитектура, шаблоны-проектирования, unity3d

Реализуем классическую схему из 3 в ряд: объект исчез - все объекты, которые находятся выше, смещаются на один ряд ниже.
Проблема: если запускать анимации для каждого из вышестоящих объектов по-отдельности, происходит заметная рассинхронизация движения. + Есть необходимость ловить событие, когда все анимации падения завершились (чтобы выполнять следующие действия\анимации и все в таком духе).
Как правильно выстроить архитектуру решения, чтобы добиться всех этих целей?
Мне приходит в голову такая реализация:

- Класс, управляющий положением объектов, проходит по списку объектов, которым пора двигаться, задает им новое положение и меняет их состояние на "в движении".
- При смене состояния каждый объект делает запись в списке "запланированные анимации".
- Когда все объекты обработаны, класс создает событие "Пора двигаться".
- Класс-проигрыватель анимаций выполняет все запланированные анимации сдвига (синхронизируя время по первой из списка, если это нужно) и по окончании всех создает событие "Сдвиги завершены".

Решение выглядит немного тяжеловесно, но оно должно решить проблему. Кроме того, оно позволит управлять и остальными анимациями (например взрыв, уничтожающий весь ряд).
Подскажите пожалуйста, как такую эту задачу решают опытные Unity разработчики?

Comment: У опытных разработчиков геймплей управляет анимацией, а не наоборот.

Comment: @user7860670 Если без прямых вызовов - почему нет. 
Как мне еще сделать логику "действие" - "анимации" - "все анимации завершились" - "следующее действие" - "анимации"?

Comment: Смысл моего предыдущего комментария сводится к тому, что связей типа *"все анимации завершились" - "следующее действие"* быть не должно. Анимации и прочие визуальные плюшки навешиваются на существующий геймплей, а не наоборот.

Comment: user7860670 вполне осознанный элемент геймдизайна: новые действия выполняются только после того, как завершились анимации по предыдущим действиям. Это же абсолютно стандартная ситуация!
В том же 3 в ряд - сдвигаются ряды и после завершения сдвига игра меняет свойство у случайных точек. Именно после завершения всех анимаций!

Comment: Нет, элемент геймдизайна - это наличие интервала времени после устранения ряда. А аудиовизуальные эффекты, сопровождающие эту паузу, навешиваются уже потом и не имеют эффекта на ход геймплея. Собственно они обычно и изготавливаются уже после либо частично параллельно с основной логикой. Это же обычная практика - отделение логики от представления.

Comment: user7860670 о варианте с задержкой по таймеру даже не думал, спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Решил вопрос благодаря @user7860670.
Проигрыватель анимаций не нужен, достаточно сделать задрежку после события и по ней же синхронизировать движение объектов.